# Wordpress installed in subdirectory on Azure webapp shows only the main page - all mod_rewrite links are broken

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, azure, mod-rewrite

I have a website that I am migrating to Azure. I have Wordpress installed in a directory (`/blog/`). Previously, the `.htaccess` controlled the redirects, allowing me to have `mywebsite.com/blog/%year%/%month%/%title%`.

Since the migration, the initial call to `mywebsite.com/blog` works fine, but any other links return a 404 not found. I know mod_rewrite doesn't work on Azure, so I created a `Web.Config` in the `/blog/` directory that contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule Blog" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="./blog/*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This doesn't work and still returns the 404 error. Others suggested that maybe doing `mysite.com/blog/index.php/2017/10/example-title` might work, but this just redirects me to `mysite.com/blog/2017/10/example-title` which displays the same 404 error.

Can anyone offer insight as to why the web.config isn't working as intended?

EDIT: I also cannot access the admin section; it too returns a 404 error.

Comment: Can you login to `wp-admin`? If you can, visiting the `permalinks-page` could fix everything. Also, double-check that you have `.htaccess` rules in place. Quick search will uncover the wordpress htaccess rules. Keep backups when editing the .htaccess file :)

Comment: I cannot access the admin page. The .htaccess doesn't work on Azure. It has to be translated to a Web.Config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `wp-config.php`, I changed the following line:

```
<?php

// ...    

define('WP_HOME', 'http://'. filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://'. filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', '/wp-content');
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
```

to:

```
<?php

// ...    

define('WP_HOME', 'http://'. filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING). '/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://'. filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING). '/blog');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', '/blog/wp-content');
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING). '/blog');
```

And I have this in my `web.config` under the `/blog/` directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="WordPress: http://aaronwp.azurewebsites.net" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And then I got it to work.

[image]